# turbolinks with coffeescript classes multiple bindings

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 4 with Turbolinks and CoffeeScript.
I CS classes and bind them to "page:update" since I'm loading items using AJAX and I need them to be part part of the CS classes as well. It goes like that:

```
$(document).on "page:update", ->
  new AnswerList $("[data-behavior='answers-list']")
```

(i'm using page:change since all other options just didn't work)
If I'm using the 'regular' "page:change", new elements that are loaded into the DOM with AJAX call, are not being part of the AnswerList class (which internally instantiate more classes for elements in the list.
with "page:update" all elements are included in the CS class but they seem to have multiple binding for events.
for example, the AnswerList has something like:

```
setEvents: ->
  @showComments.on 'click', (e) => doSomething
```

those `click` events seems to fire multiple times, depends on how many times I have loaded new items into the DOM with AJAX.

I'm also using the `jquery-turbolinks` gem which doesn't solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you're calling `@showComments.on 'click'` multiple times with the same `@showComments`, right? Which would imply that the `[data-behavior='answers-list']` selector matches things that are already on the page and new things that were just loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the case. I need to bind the events to the parents which are on the page and are never added (delegate?) so that exisitng ones wouldn't be bound again to the same event. is that right?

Comment: I'd put a delegator on a container or manually attach the event handlers in an AJAX success handler. Turbolinks might not be the right solution for your case, Turbolinks lets you pretend that an SPA is a traditional app (or vice versa) but the illusion has limits. Turbolinks seems to be aimed at apps that have very limited client-side functionality.